# What's the reason behind the different background colour on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, color

I've noticed that the background colour of Server Fault is a faded gray (which looks pink on some LCDs) background: #fdfdfd.

I'm wondering reasoning for this is because it looks weird compared to the other sites and also makes me think that something is wrong, maybe with my screen/browser. Also, why is it different from the other sites?

Comment: Why is this community wiki?

Comment: Troggy's gone philosophical on us.

Comment: -1 for random community wikiness

Comment: Doesn't hurt anyone, though.

Comment: Well, there have been quite a few questions that seem to just use wiki to avoid lost rep from a possible unpopular suggestion, answer or question. Can never know the true intentions of the OP, but can't help but wonder sometimes.

Comment: I made it community wiki originally, change the question and realized I couldn't remove the community wiki. So sorry everyone...but I didn't think it was a big deal!

Answer (score 5):

`#fdfdfd` is not a faded pink background, as it has the same values in the red, green, and blue channels.  It is a very light gray, an off-white if you will.

If it looks pink to you, it's almost certainly to do with your monitor settings.

Comment: And what's your answer to the question?

Comment: The two colors are pretty much indistinguishable on my screens.  If I had to guess (and I do, the only person who can answer you meaningfully is the person who selected the color) I'd say it's not even intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Funny: it didn't look pink to me until you complained.  I didn't even notice that it wasn't just plain white.  Now I can't look at a page without seeing a rose-tint.  Stupid Psychology mind games.

Comment: The pink is a lie.

Comment: The site is a triumph!  I'm making a comment here: HUGE SUCCESS!